# Unable to transfer app to another developer account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i'm looking for the transfer app button on itunes connect. after looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html) and tearing my hair out i still can't see any button that says transfer app on the app summary page. [image: app summary page]

has this ability been lost after apple was hacked recently?

Answer (score 3):

Apple is undergoing a massive update to their developer website. During this update there are several services that cannot be accessed including Program Enrollment and Renewals and Member Center.
Checkout the link to see what services are online: [Apple developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/)

I am as well waiting for their website to be up-to-date so I can transfer an app.

Comment: it's ironic that one of the last things to come back online is Technical Support!

Comment: I know, I've written to Technical Support 2 weeks ago exactly about the topic of App Transfer.They've replied this week that I haven't address the question to the right department (Financial Department). Now I wait again, as I resent my question to the Financial Department.  If you consider the answer as useful please vote up (I'm in need of reputation pts :P)

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted Apple as well regarding this situation.  Here is the response I received on July 31.

"Hello,

We have confirmed that you are the team agent on your account, however the App Transfer feature in iTunes Connect is temporarily unavailable and you will be unable to initiate or complete an app transfer at this time. We will contact you again as soon as this feature is available.

We appreciate your patience.

Best regards,

Holly
App Store Developer Support"

I've not received any direct contact from my support request other than this mail.  I expect when the option comes back, my new good friend Holly from Apple will contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its is gone since hack on Thursday, July 18

Answer (score 0):

The service is back online again as of 21 August 2013.